# AWS Billing Report S3 bucket grant read-permissions to another account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

So as the title suggests this is a very specific error that I've managed to find. We have one account that holds all the billing data and which is then stored to S3 bucket as hourly reports.

Then however we have another account that has an EC2 instance for which we'd like to grant GetObject permissions on our billing-bucket. Yet I am unable to do so, is it because AWS CloudWatch as it uploads the reports to S3 it does not set the acl to bucket-owner-full-control? I am at loss why this is happening.

```
fatal error: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden
```

That is the error as I try to copy a `hourly-Manifest.json` object from the billing bucket using my EC2 instance's AWS-CLI.

The permissions are set from the billing-account as following where the Principal is the second account root.

```
{
      "Sid": "ClaudiaReadOnly",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
          "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:root"
      },
      "Action": [
        "s3:Get*",
        "s3:List*"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::billing-bucket",
        "arn:aws:s3:::billing-bucket/billing/*"
      ]
}
```

The second account grants permissions to the EC2 instance using CloudFormation template with again same Get* and List* permissions.

If we set single object's Read-permission directly from the console for the second account we are able to copy it using the EC2 instance's AWS-CLI. But then for each other object we get the same 403 error.

Very frustrating to debug this issue and I wish AWS had little better information about this matter...

Comment: Have you tried creating a cross-account role through to your billing account from your other account and then attaching this to your EC2 instance. Using something like https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html

Comment: you might also need `s3:GetBucketLocation`  and `s3:ListBucket` for cross-account access.

Comment: @NickBrown that is what I'm going to try tomorrow. This however means that I can no longer create the profile in the CloudFormation template if I create it in the billing account.

Comment: @SudharsanSivasankaran Get* and List* should include those actions am I right? And we specified both the bucket itself and the file path as resources.

Comment: can you post your policy?

Comment: @SudharsanSivasankaran I edited my question to include the policy.

Comment: Are you instance role for the ec2 instance? In that case, this `arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:root` should be the ec2 instance role instead of the root.

Comment: @SudharsanSivasankaran but shouldn't giving permissions to root account enable the root account the ability to again give them as permissions to its children roles/accounts? I mean I am able to list objects but not copy them so clearly it works. Even so the instance role is generated by CloudFormation so the id is not static. Sure you could make it static but again kinda messy.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that a different account (AWS Billing) creates your billing reports in your billing bucket, and this leads you into the murky world of S3 object ACLs - see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/acl-overview.html

If you were accessing the S3 bucket from your billing account, you won't have issues as the billing account is the bucket owner and is always granted access, however for other accounts, the only way to grant access is for either the writer (AWS Billing) to set appropriate ACLs on copy (this won't happen), or to retrospectively modify the ACLs.

Here is default object ACL that is created for a billing report:

```
$ aws s3api get-object-acl --bucket my-billing-bucket --key reports/xxx/xxx.json
{
    "Owner": {
        "DisplayName": "aws-billpresentation+artifact-storage",
        "ID": "aaaaaaaaaa"
    },
    "Grants": [
        {
            "Grantee": {
                "DisplayName": "aws-billpresentation+artifact-storage",
                "ID": "aaaaaaaaaa",
                "Type": "CanonicalUser"
            },
            "Permission": "FULL_CONTROL"
        },
        {
            "Grantee": {
                "DisplayName": "mybilling",
                "ID": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
                "Type": "CanonicalUser"
            },
            "Permission": "FULL_CONTROL"
        }
    ]
}
```

IN the example above, aws-billpresentation+artifact-storage is the name of the AWS billing account that writes your reports, whilst mybiling is the name of the billing account where your bucket resides.

If you wanted to grant read access to another account, you would need to find out the canonical ID of that account and then add a READ grant, repeating this for every file.  For example:

```
aws s3api put-object-acl --bucket my-billing-bucket --key reports/xxx/xxx.json --access-control-policy '{
 "Owner": {
     "DisplayName": "aws-billpresentation+artifact-storage",
     "ID": "aaaaaaaa"
 },
 "Grants": [
     {
         "Grantee": {
             "DisplayName": "aws-billpresentation+artifact-storage",
             "ID": "aaaaaaaa",
             "Type": "CanonicalUser"
         },
         "Permission": "FULL_CONTROL"
     },
     {
         "Grantee": {
             "DisplayName": "mybilling",
             "ID": "xxxxxxxx",
             "Type": "CanonicalUser"
         },
         "Permission": "FULL_CONTROL"
     },
     {
         "Grantee": {
             "DisplayName": "myotheraccount",
             "ID": "yyyyyyyy",
             "Type": "CanonicalUser"
         },
         "Permission": "READ"
     }
   ]
}'
```

The simplest option is to publish reports into the account where you want to actually process the reports, which avoids all of the S3 object ACL issues.